# how to find the mac address of DNS server?

Tags: unix, networking, tcp, network-programming

how can i  find the mac address of DNS server?

Answer (score 2):

If you're on Windows, try typing `arp -a` which lists the IP addresses and MAC addresses that your PC knows about.

Answer (score 2):

if you know the IP address of the server then write `arp -a <server_IP_address>` in command prompt to get MAC address of the Server.

Otherwise follow the steps below.

```
1. Opens the DOS command prompt (write cmd in Run window) 

2. Enter "ping <server_name>" into the command prompt. It will return your server's IP address. 

3. Type "arp -a <server_IP_address>" into the command prompt. This will return server's MAC/Physical address.
```

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `arp` (available in most OS) or [`arping`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arping) utilities.